# How can I turn a 1x3 matrix into a one dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I'm making a function to calculate a dot product when given two vectors. The code is later used in a matrix multiplication function. The issue I'm having is that the parameters passed in from the matrix multiplication function are 1x3 matrices that in order to multiply together, I need to use dot+=A[0,,i]*B[0,i]. The submission website expects dot+=A[i],B[i] and I'm not sure how to get my matrices converted to arrays.                                                                   [Picture of my two functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMW0z.png)

I tried recreating the matrices and isolating rows but I still had [[1,2,3]] come up and mes with my dot product function.

Comment: Hi, is there a specific reason you're not using [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)? It is **extremely** inefficient to implement dot product the way you're doing. I see you're going to use it for machine learning - manual implementation will slow down your your algorithm by orders of magnitude.

Comment: No images of code. [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the numpy library to perform matrix multiplication.

You can use the `numpy.matmul` function to perform matrix multiplication. Read more about it here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

You can also use the numpy.dot function to perform dot product. Read more about it here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Here is an example of how to use the numpy library to perform matrix multiplication:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

c = np.matmul(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at your image, I noticed the use of `np.matrix`.  Be careful with that.  That's an array subclass designed years ago to make `numpy` more friendly to wayward MATLAB users.  It's use is discouraged now.

A key difference is that it must always be 2d:

```
In [108]: M = np.matrix([1,2,3])    
In [109]: M
Out[109]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])   # note the added dimension    
In [110]: M.shape
Out[110]: (1, 3)
```

And `ravel` doesn't remove that leading dimension:

```
In [111]: M.ravel()
Out[111]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

`np.matrix` does have a `A1` property, which ravels and converts to `ndarray`, or rather converts to array and ravels:

```
In [112]: M.A1
Out[112]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`np.matrix` does matrix multiplication with using `*`, though now `@` is recommended operator that works with `ndarray` as well

```
In [113]: M*M
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[113], line 1
----> 1 M*M

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py:218, in matrix.__mul__(self, other)
    215 def __mul__(self, other):
    216     if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    217         # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 218         return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    219     if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    220         return N.dot(self, other)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

With a (1,3) shape, we have to use a transpose to do `dot`, producing (3,3) one way:

```
In [114]: M.T*M           # (3,1) with (1,3) => (3,3)
Out[114]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [3, 6, 9]])
```

or (1,1) the other:

```
In [115]: M*M.T         # (1,3) with (3,1) => (1,1)
Out[115]: matrix([[14]])
```

where as using the 1d `A1` gives a scalar, dot product:

```
In [116]: M.A1 @ M.A1
Out[116]: 14
```

While you are welcome to implement your own `dot` (for learning purpose, I assume), be aware that `numpy` has good code to do this for you.

```
 np.dot
 np.matmul
 np.einsum
```

Note that `dot` and `matmul` extend the usual 2d matrix multiplication, with special rules for 1d arrays, and for 3+d.  But the key pairing is "last dim A pairs with the 2nd to the last of B", the usual "across columns, down rows" we learned as kids.